# can't run migration

Tags: mysql, migration, rubygems

I run

```
  rake db:create
```

and getting strange error

```
     rake aborted!
   126: ═х эрщфхэ єърчрээ√щ ьюфєы№.   - C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mysql2-
   0.3.11-x86-mingw32/lib/mysql2/1.9/mysql2.so
```

I tried to reinstall bundler.
Is it gem problem ?

Comment: experiencing the very same problem, did you find a solution?

Comment: @ile, I moved to sqlite3) Sorry, it was three months ago, I don't remember solution.

Comment: I found a solution, will post it below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this problem, reference to the following link:
http://maxivak.com/installing-mysql2-gem-on-ruby-1-9-2-and-rails-3-0-5-on-windows/

You need to include mysql-connector through the Rails DevKit.